# How to Dynamically change a YouTube video

Tags: php, jquery, session, video, youtube

I have a YouTube player on my page, the src comes from the session `$_SESSION['video']['code']` which contains the YouTube video `id`.

I need it to change video when the PHP session is updated without reloading the page. Preferably with Jquery, but I'm open to others. My current code is below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  refresTa();
});

function refresTa(){
    $('.now_playing').load('../beta.php', function(){
       setTimeout(refresTa, 1000);
    });
}
```

The problem with it is  it keeps refreshing the video, making it unplayable. is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.load()` on `.now_playing`, fetch the data from PHP elsewhere, and call `refresTa()` only when needed. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    myCheck();
});

function myCheck() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        var myData = data.myData;

        // do something based on data received

        // call this function again
        setTimeout(function(){
            myCheck();
        }, 10000); // every 10 seconds
    });
}
```

In `ajax.php`, you can output the data back to Javascript with `json_encode()`:

```
$returnArray = array("myData"=>$data);
exit(json_encode($returnArray));
```